# How to add pivot table to pivot table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1, pivot-table

My DB is something like that : participant <=> event

I have a table "event_participant" to link the two others.

Now I want a new table : "Eat", that adds dinner's date for each day of an event for a participant.

I imagine table "Eat" like that : event_id, participant_id, date

But maybe it's better to do so : event_participant_id, date

Or maybe there's another way; you tell me.

I use Eloquent for Laravel 5.1 but any SQL answer could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Assuming your participant table***

```
id  |  participant_fname   |  participant_lname  |  created_at  |  updated_at
    |                      |                     |              |
```

---

***Assuming your event table***

```
id  |  event_name  |  created_at  |  updated_at
    |              |              |
```

---

***Assuming your event_participant table***

```
id  |  participant_id    |  event_id  |  created_at  |  updated_at
    |                    |            |              |
```

---

As you have mentioned for the new ***`Eat`*** table, you could save the primary key of ***`event_participant`*** table. By doing so you could fetch the Event and Participant related details by doing a JOIN query. Both this table would be Pivot tables.

***Eat table***

```
id  |  event_participant_id   |  created_at  |  updated_at
    |                         |              |
```

***Eloquent Relations***

[Laravel Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Within your model you could then include the relationships between each tables to fetch values using Eloquent Relations

[image]
Hope this is helpful.